# calculate y and width, just like Google calendar

Tags: php, algorithm

in PHP, i'm trying to figure out how i efficiently can calculate the position in the X and the width.

Given is an array with the position in pixels. But they all have the same width and y. So when there are in the same period, they will overlay each other. I want them to be smaller and in the right Y position based on the other blocks that are related.

For the friday in the example the array starts this way:

```
{
   "2013-01-11":[
      {
         "width":114,
         "left":0,
         "top":260,
         "height":100
      },
      {
         "width":114,
         "left":0,
         "top":300,
         "height":100
      },
      {
         "width":114,
         "left":0,
         "top":360,
         "height":100
      },
      {
         "width":114,
         "left":0,
         "top":400,
         "height":100
      }
    ]
}
```

In the printscreen you can see how i want it to be. A block can also have 3 or more blocks in the same time period.

[image: current situation]

Comment: My goodness, that's a lot of paintball for one day ;)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436306/calendar-day-view-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Two naive approaches are to keep track of which times are busy, either by keeping a lookup table based on the discreet steps for a single day (08:00, 08:30, 09:00, etc), or by checking all previous events for the same day, and detecting overlap that way.

As both the number of events for a single day and the number of discreet intervals are rather low, I think a naive approach would work fine and could easily be understood later.

This assumes that the events are sorted by starttime.

In pseudocode / pythonish:

```
intervals = []

for event in events:
    time = event['starttime']
    columnoffset = 0

    while (time < event['endtime']):
        # check if this time space already has events assigned
        if (intervals[time] and columnoffset < intervals[time]):
            columnoffset = intervals[time]

        # count the event
        intervals[time]++

        # increment time bin
        time += discreet_step_size

    # set new x position based on how many columns were busy within this interval
    event['x'] = event['x'] + columnoffset * xoffset
```

Answer (score -1):

/* using GD library*/

$im=imagecreatefromjpeg("imagename.jpg");

```
$w = imagesx($im);
$h = imagesy($im);

echo "width of page=".$w."</br>";//width of whole page
echo "height of page=".$h."</br>";//height of whole page

//reading pixels by pixels
for($i=0;$i<$w;$i++){

for($j=0;$j<$h;$j++){

        $rgb = imagecolorat($im,$i,$j);
        $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $b = $rgb & 0xFF;

        //comparing the value of rgb if found then excute  
        if ($r= && $ $g= && $b=)
        {
                   apply condition here;   
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I think u misunderstood the question. the problem has nothing to do with graphics.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the question, regardless of how you read it.

Comment: sorry but i think this is related with graphics.